# How to use jQuery to retrieve a copy of the DOM to modify in memory only

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Is it possible to use jQuery to grab a specific part of the DOM into a variable as a jQuery Object upon which I can then perform some action(s) without affecting the DOM itself.  When I say I don't want to affect the DOM, I do not want the changes to be visible to the user, but cannot simply be hidden via CSS.

The scenario is as follows.  I want to grab a specifc div's contents, make a few changes to it, surround the content in another  tag and post that back to the server via ajax to generate a PDF document.

Right now I am grabbing the div I need via:

```
var mainDiv = $(sourceSelector + " div").filter(function (index, element) {
if ($(this).hasClass("ABC_Page") && $(this).is(":visible")) return true;
});
```

Problem is if I then do something like this:

```
$mainDiv.find("#MyOtherDiv").append("<span>New content</span>");
```

I see the changes on the page, when I only want them in the in memory copy.  Based on the jQuery documentation I thought `filter()` would create a new object and not reflect changes back to the web page.

Thanks

Comment: Could you do `$mainDiv = $mainDiv.clone();`? This should create a deep-copy in memory that could be edited I think. Not 100% on that but it may be worth a try. Reference: [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)...

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the clone() jQuery function.
https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

You should be using .clone() to make a copy.  You can then modify them before inserting back into the document (or not in your case).

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

You could use .clone() method: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

As stated in the documentation:

> Note: When using the .clone() method, you can modify the cloned
>   elements or their contents before (re-)inserting them into the
>   document.

Just use this syntax: `$clonedElement = $(selector).clone( true )`